# How can I use conditional formatting to compare against a dynamic worksheet?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I am trying to use conditional formatting to compare the value of one cell against another in a dynamically referenced worksheet while using a dynamic cell reference and highlight the cell whenever the values do not match.

I have created a master sheet containing a cell with the name of the worksheet I wish to reference. This cell will be updated periodically with the name of the relevant worksheet. I am able to write a formula that correctly returns the value I wish to compare, but when I enter this expression in the conditional format rule (format cells if is not equal to) I am given a red outline with the message "Invalid formula".

I have tried various combinations such as using a custom formula and using (current cell = (formula here)) and while I am not given an error, it still does not work as intended.

I am comparing the value of cell C2 in worksheet 4719 to cell C2 in worksheet 4717. A cell in a worksheet called Mastersheet contains the entry "4717" in B1, and this is the cell that will be periodically changed to something like 4717 for example.

The formula that is able to successfully return the value I am after is `=indirect(Mastersheet!B1&"!"&"C2")` but I was only able to accomplish this by putting the `"C2"` reference in quotation marks, which is not dynamic and thus would have to be manually changed to work for any of the other values in column C.

I expect cell C1 in worksheet 4719 to turn green as the value there is different from cell C1 in worksheet 4718.

I made a publicly viewable copy of my Google sheet if my explanation does not make enough sense https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s0oaGas46akmGV7hapnDOdhndcWudyq239kmCrLnt3U/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

try it like this:

```
=INDIRECT(Mastersheet!$B$1&"!"&ADDRESS(ROW(C2), COLUMN(C2), 4))
```

[image: 0]

---

this can be used in Conditional formatting, however, referenced sheet cant be fully active so:

```
=INDIRECT(INDIRECT("Mastersheet!B1")&"!"&ADDRESS(ROW(C2),COLUMN(C2),4))
```

[image: 0]

---

this can be further moded so the B1 would be dynamic too:

```
=INDIRECT(INDIRECT("Mastersheet!"&ADDRESS(ROW(B1),COLUMN(B1)))&"!"&
 ADDRESS(ROW(C2),COLUMN(C2),4))=19
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I don't think this works in conditional formatting though?

Comment: Hi, thanks for this suggestion, but as Tom Sharpe pointed out, it does not appear to work with conditional formatting :(

Comment: Yes that's really neat - the inner indirect evaluates to a string so the outer indirect is OK with it in conditional formatting.